# Unmarshal _id to id wont work

Tags: json, mongodb, go

So my structure looks like this:

```
type Article struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    LangCode string `json:"langCode" bson:"langCode"`
    AuthorId string `json:"authorId" bson:"authorId"`
    AuthorName string `json:"authorName" bson:"authorName"`
    ArticleType int64 `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Title string `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Intro string `json:"intro" bson:"intro"`
    Body string `json:"body" bson:"body"`
    MainPic string `json:"mainPic" bson:"mainPic"`
    Tags string `json:"tags" bson:"tags"`
    Slug string `json:"slug" bson:"slug"`
    DateAdded time.Time `json:"dateAdded" bson:"dateAdded"`
    Status int64 `json:"status" bson:"status"`
}
```

And following snippet:

```
pageReturn.Pagination = resultsList.Pagination
err = json.Unmarshal(resultsList.Results, &pageReturn.Articles)
```

Will return data without value _id from database (I mean in json string id will be equal to "")

If I change     ID bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
to     ID bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`

value will be returned normally (actual _id value from db will be returned)

I'm wondering how can I avoid this (but I still need to use json.Unmarshal)

Comment: ID bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"` ? (json:"_id" instead of json:"id")

Comment: @StephaneMartin  I mean if I change it like that in definition of Article struct it will work, but I need my output to contain string "id" instead of "_id"

Comment: you need two different struct types, one to Unmarshal, one to Marshal. See answer :)

Comment: I was pretty convenient that I can somehow avoid additional structure, like if I am not using unmarshal output will be whatever i put as value for json fields. Thanks for the answer anyhow, but I will wait a bit more to see is there a different solution.

Comment: Another possibility is to define the MarshalJson method for your Article struct to customize the marshaling. Probably needs more code, though.

Answer (score 1):

- Unmarshal into your Article struct, but with tag `json:"_id"`
- two struct types that only differ by tags can be converted to each other. So one solution is to create another ArticleBis type, with tag `json:"id"` instead. Then you convert your article to an ArticleBis instance, which you Marshal.

Another simple example:

```go
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Base struct {
    Firstname string `json:"first"`
}

type A struct {
    Base
    Lastname string `json:"last"`
}

type B struct {
    Base
    Lastname string `json:"lastname"`
}

func main() {
    john := A{Base: Base{Firstname: "John"}, Lastname:"Doe"}
    john1 := B(john)
    john_json, _ := json.Marshal(john)
    john1_json, _ := json.Marshal(john1)
    fmt.Println(string(john_json))
    fmt.Println(string(john1_json))
}
```